# accessing enum types got an error using c# in winforms

Tags: c#, winforms, enums

hi i have problem with enum types

I am doing like this....

```
namspace XXXXXXxx
{
 public partial class form1:form
  {

          ////////
       and i am checking the listview selected item with enum type by the             following code
      private void lstviewcategories_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
      {

          if (lstviewcategories.SelectedItems[0].ToString() == categorytype.type1.ToString())
            { 

                    /////
                       blah blah...
            }
       }
           and  at here i am defining enum like this...
    public enum categorytype
    {
       type1 = "ALL",
         type2 ="0-500",
       type3 ="500-1000" ,
        type4 ="1000+ "                    
    }
  }

}
```

I am getting error at these lines **type1 = "ALL",**  t**ype2 ="0-500",type3 ="500-1000"** **,type4 ="1000+"**  say cannot implicitly convert type string to int

how can i defined these as enum

how can i access and compare with listviewcategoriesitems.....

would any one pls help on this......

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't define enums as string values - enums are effectively named numbers. If you want string constants, you'll just have to use:

```
public const string Type1 = "ALL";
public const string Type2 = "0-500";
```

... etc. If you need an enum for use elsewhere, you could either create a `Dictionary<CategoryType, string>` and possibly a reverse mapping as well, or decorate each enum value with a string in an attribute (e.g. `[Description("ALL")]`) which you can retrieve at execution time. It's slightly awkward, but not too hard.

(Also note that C# is case-sensitive - there's no class `form` to derive from, and it's well worth following the [.NET naming conventions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229045.aspx) to make your code easier to read for other developers.)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `struct` instead:

```
struct CategoryType
{
    public const string Type1 = "ALL";
    public const string Type2 = "0-500";
    public const string Type3 = "500-1000";
    public const string Type4 = "1000+";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
public enum categorytype
{
   ALL=1,
   From0TO500=2,
   From500To1000=3 ,
   From1000=4                    
}
```

so you should change the values of `lstviewcategories` items with `1,2,3, and 4`

```
if(lstviewcategories.SelectedValue == categorytype.All.ToString())
{
   .................. 
}
```

or cast the `SelectedValue` of `lstviewcategories` to enum then compare

```
categorytype mycategorytype = (categorytype)[Enum].Parse(Typeof(categorytype),lstviewcategories.SelectedValue);
if(mycategorytype == categorytype.All)
{
   .................. 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't assign `String` values to `Enums`, they are accept only number such as int, byte, long, and etc... .

Answer (score 0):

As stated [here on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sbbt4032%28v=VS.100%29.aspx) an `Enum` can be based on the simple numeric value types,

`byte`, `sbyte`, `short`, `ushort`, `int`, `uint`, `long`, or `ulong`

so, not `String`, like in your definition.